# Obscuring the ball from the opponent

Tags: rules, rugby

Can a player pretend to pass the ball to another and the second player pretend or act as if they have it, while obscuring the ball from the opposition?

I was watching the animated TV series *All Out!!*/*オールアウト!!* (a show about a rugby team) and [they did such a manoeuvre](https://media.giphy.com/media/Lp9BXtuI5YDSWxKd3z/giphy.gif).

Was this legal?

Comment: Anecdotally - I played rugby for a university that was top 20... I was a big/fast and very unskilled wing.   I had one of the best fullbacks in the country next to me.   We ran this exact switch basically whenever we could - this only doable under pretty exact circumstances for wing/fullback.   But we would do the same "hide" and if I didn't have the ball one my favorite things was crouching to get low to take a hit and stumbling down to the ground.    I can't see this being illegal in any league unless the person without the ball "blocks" someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a referee, having looked at that it's not at all illegal. It is the equivalent of a dummy, where the player pretends to pass but doesn't.

The reasons for disallowing this would be if either player obstructed the opposition, which they don't.

If the dummy occurred at a scrum, it is penalised by a free kick under Law [19.38.f](https://laws.worldrugby.org/?law=19).